# ROS indigo installation fails on Raspberry pi 2 and 3

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to follow the instructions below to install ROS indego on raspberry pi 2 and 3,
http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi

Both failed. I used latest image from raspberry website.

Raspberry pi 2 failure - Failing while installing **liblz4-dev**.
**apt-get source -b lz4** command just runs for a very long time and gives below error

```
Read : 66 MB   ==> 59.22%   ^CMakefile:226: recipe for target 'test-lz4-basic' failed
make[3]: *** [test-lz4-basic] Interrupt
Makefile:98: recipe for target 'test' failed
make[2]: *** [test] Interrupt
debian/rules:47: recipe for target 'override_dh_auto_test' failed
make[1]: *** [override_dh_auto_test] Interrupt
debian/rules:33: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build died from signal 2
```

Raspberry pi 3 failure - Failing during python installation stage,

**sudo apt-get install python-pip python-setuptools python-yaml python-distribute python-docutils python-dateutil python-six**

Error message

```
sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Do we have any recent image of raspbian Jessie with ROS Indigo installed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248261/ros-indigo-installation-fails-on-raspberry-pi-2-and-3/) by [VictorAbraham](https://answers.ros.org/users/28547/victorabraham/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just asking:

```
Read : 66 MB   ==> 59.22%   ^CMakefile
```

That `^`, is that a control character (ie: the `ctrl` in `ctrl+c`)? I'm asking because `make` then reports `[test-lz4-basic] Interrupt`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0